# How to modify the Path filter so it will trigger only the desired pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, build, azure-pipelines

Inside one repository I'm managing three different solutions (I know - bad practice)

1. `MySolution.sln`
2. `Child solution A/SolutionA.sln`
3. `Child solution B/SolutionB.sln`

Like here in the example:

[image]

Each solution has its **own** yml pipelines:

1. `Main-Pipeline`
2. `Child-A-Pipeline`
3. `Child-B-Pipeline`

My goal is to make only a specific pipeline to be triggered when its related code has been modified:

For example:

1. If something inside the folder `Child solution A` had some changes, only the pipeline `Child-A-Pipeline` should to be triggered.
2. IF something outside the folders `Child solution A` or `Child solution B` had some changes, only the pipeline `Main-Pipeline` should be triggered.

I've tried modifying the *Path filter* property located inside *Build Validation*

[image]

This solution triggers all three pipeline when something in the entire code has changed:

1. `Main-Pipeline` -> `/*; !/Child solution A/*; !/Child solution B/*`
2. `Child-A-Pipeline` -> `/Child solution A/*`
3. `Child-B-Pipeline` -> `/Child solution B/*`

This solution does not triggers the `Main-Pipeline` at all:

1. `Main-Pipeline` -> `!/Child solution A/*; !/Child solution B/*`
2. `Child-A-Pipeline` -> `/Child solution A/*`
3. `Child-B-Pipeline` -> `/Child solution B/*`

**How to modify the *Path filter* property of the `Main-Pipeline` so it will be trigged if and only if the source code had some changes outside the children folders?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to modify the Path filter property of the Main-Pipeline so it will be trigged if and only if the source code had some changes outside the children folders?

I have created a sample demo based on your info, and the test turned out that your first setup was correct and it works for me now.

```
1. `Main-Pipeline` -> `/*;!/Child solution A/*;!/Child solution B/*`
2. `Child-A-Pipeline` -> `/Child solution A/*`
3. `Child-B-Pipeline` -> `/Child solution B/*`
```

**Note**: Besides, check if spaces in path filter `/*;!/Child solution A/*;!/Child solution B/*` will affect you.

The test result:

Changing the source code outside the children folders, like the `README.md` in below repo:

[image]

[image]

Only the Main-Pipeline was triggered:

[image]

Obviously the filtering is working as expected, not sure if I understand any difference in what you say when something in the entire code has change, if this is different from the changes you did please let me know how you did it

Comment: It worked, I assume this `/*; !/Child solution A/*; !/Child solution B/*` does not work because of `; ` (extra space)

Comment: @ShaharShokrani, Glad to know that work for you. I have updated the answer to highlight solution. Thanks for your feedback.